# Change language format of records stored with another language

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a database with several columns in `datetime` and `datetime2` format, before distributing my program written in vb.net that uses this database, I had set the language in Italian on the login 'sa' (in the account options as default language) and then I received from the various inserts and select dates in `dd/mm/yyyy` format.

The other day for forgetfulness, I forgot to set the Italian language, and then users have stored the dates in `yyyy/dd/mm` format.

I immediately limited the damage as I immediately set the language to Italian, but now I find some records stored with `yyyy/dd/mm`.

How do I convert the old records inserted in the incorrect format into Italian, in order to receive the dates in the correct format?

Comment: Dates aren't stored in a format; they're binary values. If they're being stored in a format, that aren't a `date`, they're a `varchar` and that is a much bigger problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is too long for a comment.

Something is amiss in your explanation.  All the `date`/`time` data types in SQL Server store the values using an *internal* format.  The formatting for input and output is what `dateformat` and the internationalization settings control.

So, this code:

```
create table t (d datetime);

set dateformat ymd;
insert into t values ('2020-01-02')   -- January 2nd

set dateformat ydm;
insert into t values ('2020-01-02')   -- February 1st

set dateformat ymd;
select * from t;
```

Returns the correct dates, both in YYYY-MM-DD format.  [Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=476ad6e0031800f97538049f8639ba7d) is a db<>fiddle.

What could be happening?  Two things I can think of:

- The internationalization settings can be set on a per-session basis, so there might be open sessions using old settings.
- Your code might be storing dates as strings *using default formats*.  That is a bad idea in a real application.  You'll probably have to change them one at a time.

Comment: I am attaching a picture of the record problem:

Keep in mind that I insert the data in this format: "dd / MM / yyyy" (31/12/2020)

![a busy cat](https://i.ibb.co/bP1YD1W/forum.jpg)

Comment: Are you sure the column is not a string?  It sounds like the data was misinterpreted when it was inserted.  You'll need to use `update` to fix it.

Comment: thanks Gordon for your help.
I have misinterpreted the date, the error is due to the bad interpretation of the data string coming from the program. The database has entered all dates correctly. Thanks to everyone for the help. I put as solved